# Selenium + Python Click on Search Selects but Does Not Click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have all of my options selected on [this form](https://willmyphonework.net/AdvanceLookup) and have the following code to click the Search button:

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "alMatchFrequencies"))).click()
```

I have also tried this:

```
search = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "alMatchFrequencies")))
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I have also tried subbing in RETURN instead of ENTER.

Here is a screenshot after that line is run:

[image]

The search bar is highlighted, but no results are being displayed. I can replicate this screen on my own and am able to press the search button so I don't think it is missing fields.

Comment: Just to check smth: try waiting for 30-40 seconds after you filled up the last filter and before clicking Search. Any difference?

Comment: Are you getting any errors/ exceptions?

Comment: @Sureshmani No errors or exceptions. The console is clean.

Comment: @alecxe Tried a 30 second wait and that did not help. ):

Comment: Did you try with JavaScript executor for this click()?

Comment: `wd.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", search)`

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for that snippet. I tried running that as well. No errors and still no results displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are actually clicking the search button but are not seeing the results because they are below the view you show. The scrollable area in your screenshot was a clue. 
Clicking the search button is as easy as `search.click()` after you've executed the selector. But then you need to wait and scroll the page.

To Scroll a page you need to introduce[ActionChains](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains) in the Selenium library and to wait for the load you'll need to use Python's `time.sleep(sec)` function.

Full code to produce the attached picture:

```
#Imports
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#...Code to Load and Select Filters...#

search = WebDriverWait(wd, 3000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "alMatchFrequencies")))
search.click()
# Wait for element to load
time.sleep(3)
# Locate element to scroll to
results = WebDriverWait(wd,3000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[5]")))
actions = ActionChains(wd)
# Scroll
actions.move_to_element(results).perform()
wd.get_screenshot_as_file("test3.png")
```

[image: Result]